# SDN k shortest path with pyretic

Tags: sdn

can anybody help me with this code?
if i run this code with pyretic, the pyretic will says

```
File "/home/ibrahim/pyretic/pyretic.py", line 313, in <module>
main()
File "/home/ibrahim/pyretic/pyretic.py", line 191, in main
module = import_module(module_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/ibrahim/pyretic/pyretic/examples/kshortestpathpyretic.py", line 58
distances[node_start]=0

                ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

[What s wrong with this code if i run this codewith pyretic](http://csie.nqu.edu.tw/smallko/sdn/pyretic_yenksp.htm)

[the image is the result if i run this code with pyretic controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AJQ5.png)

Answer (score 0):

as the error messages said, You need to correct the indentation (tab between blocks) in the python source code.

I can't see your code as the link is not available.

Comment: /home/ibrahim/pyretic/pyretic/examples/kshortestpathpyretic.py  this file.

Comment: i dont know how to fix my problem, would you give me your email please, so that i can send my code to you,,? @engbarakat